# Sum variable ranges VBA by fixing the first column

Tags: vba, dynamic, sum, range

I want to know how can I do a sum of a range by fixing a column, and then save the value into an array.

```
A  B  C  D  E  F  G
1  -  10 -  4  -  1
2  -  98 -  1  -  2
3  -  5  -  9  -  7
4  -  80 -  54 -  10
```

What I am trying to do is:

1. Sum the values from column A -> put the sum into a sumArray()
2. Sum the values from column A to C -> put the sum into a sumArray
3. Sum the values from column A to E -> put the sum into a sumArray
4. Sum the values from column A to G -> put the sum into a sumArray

Basically, the dimension of columns and rows are dynamic. My question is how can I do this?

I hope I had explained myself properly

Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: Put `=IF(MOD(COLUMN(),2)=1,SUM($A$1:A$4),"")` in A5 and copy/drag over to G5.

Comment: Actually, the dimension will increase in columns and rows. And in the rows, it is not followed. I mean it will have to do from a specific dimension in rows, and then have to repeat from X to X rows.

Comment: So given the dataset above, what and where would be the output?

Comment: @ScottCraner, the output is a sumArray. I mean sumArray(0) = 1+2+3+4 = 10 (sum of column A). sumArray(1) = 10+98+5+80 = 193 (column C). sumArray(2) = 4+1+9+54 = 68 (column E). sumArray(3) = 1+2+7+10 = 20 (column G).

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub summarize()
Dim i As Integer
Dim maxCol, maxRow As Integer
maxCol = 6
maxRow = 7
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet

Dim sumArray(100) As Integer
For i = 1 To maxCol
    maxRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row
    sumArray(i) = CInt(Application.Sum(ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(maxRow, i))))
    Debug.Print sumArray(i)
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: In this case you should know the last row with value in the i column. You can do it with this :
lastline = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row

Comment: I think your code may work for the example I wrote above. However, if the total columns and rows needed, change it won't work. Thank you for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

you could use this:

```
Sub DoSumArray()
    Dim icol As Long

    With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        ReDim SumArray(1 To .columns.Count / 2 + 1)
        For icol = 1 To .columns.Count Step 2
            SumArray(icol \ 2 + 1) = WorksheetFunction.SUM(.columns(icol))
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```